# Creating a matplotlib or seaborn histogram which uses percent rather than count?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataset, histogram

Specifically I'm dealing with the Kaggle Titanic dataset. I've plotted a stacked histogram which shows ages that survived and died upon the titanic. Code below.

```
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.hist([data[data['Survived']==1]['Age'], data[data['Survived']==0]['Age']], stacked=True, bins=30, label=['Survived','Dead'])
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Number of passengers')
plt.legend()
```

I would like to alter the chart to show a single chart per bin of the percentage in that age group that survived. E.g. if a bin contained the ages between 10-20 years of age and 60% of people aboard the titanic in that age group survived, then the height would line up 60% along the y-axis.

Edit: I may have given a poor explanation to what I'm looking for. Rather than alter the y-axis values, I'm looking to change the actual shape of the bars based on the percentage that survived.

The first bin on the graph shows roughly 65% survived in that age group. I would like this bin to line up against the y-axis at 65%. The following bins look to be 90%, 50%, 10% respectively, and so on.

[image]

The graph would end up actually looking something like this:

[image]

Comment: The library Dexplot is able to create a stacked bar plot of percentages. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52692726/3707607).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following will help ...

1. Split the dataframe based on 'Survived'

   ```py
   df_survived=df[df['Survived']==1]
   df_not_survive=df[df['Survived']==0]
   ```
2. Create Bins

   ```py
   age_bins=np.linspace(0,80,21)
   ```
3. Use np.histogram to generate histogram data

   ```py
   survived_hist=np.histogram(df_survived['Age'],bins=age_bins,range=(0,80))
   not_survive_hist=np.histogram(df_not_survive['Age'],bins=age_bins,range=(0,80))
   ```
4. Calculate survival rate in each bin

   ```py
   surv_rates=survived_hist[0]/(survived_hist[0]+not_survive_hist[0])
   ```
5. Plot

   ```py
   plt.bar(age_bins[:-1],surv_rates,width=age_bins[1]-age_bins[0])
   plt.xlabel('Age')
   plt.ylabel('Survival Rate')
   ```

[image]

Comment: to avoid all floating values rounded to 0. Use the following `from __future__ import division`

Answer (score 5):

For Seaborn, use the parameter `stat`. According to the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), currently supported values for the `stat` parameter are:

- `count` shows the number of observations
- `frequency` shows the number of observations divided by the bin width
- `density` normalizes counts so that the area of the histogram is 1
- `probability` normalizes counts so that the sum of the bar heights is 1
- `percent` normalize such that bar heights sum to 100

The result with `stat` being `count`:

```py
seaborn.histplot(
    data=data,
    x='variable',
    discrete=True,
    stat='count'
)
```

[image: Histogram result for stat=count]

The result after `stat` is changed to `probability`:

```py
seaborn.histplot(
    data=data,
    x='variable',
    discrete=True,
    stat='probability'
)
```

[image: Histogram result for stat=probability]

Comment: What if I want the y-axis to be represented as a percentage, i.e. from 0-100 instead of 0-1? Edit: figured it out. Set `stat = 'percent'`

Answer (score 2):

`pd.Series.hist` uses `np.histogram` underneath.

Let's explore that

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
d = np.histogram(s, normed=True)
print('\nthese are the normalized counts\n')
print(d[0])
print('\nthese are the bin values, or average of the bin edges\n')
print(d[1])

these are the normalized counts

[ 0.11552497  0.18483996  0.06931498  0.32346993  0.39278491  0.36967992
  0.32346993  0.25415494  0.25415494  0.02310499]

these are the bin edges

[-2.25905503 -1.82624818 -1.39344133 -0.96063448 -0.52782764 -0.09502079
  0.33778606  0.77059291  1.20339976  1.6362066   2.06901345]
```

We can plot these while calculating the mean bin edges

```
pd.Series(d[0], pd.Series(d[1]).rolling(2).mean().dropna().round(2).values).plot.bar()
```

[image]

***ACTUAL ANSWER***
OR

We could have simply passed `normed=True` to the `pd.Series.hist` method.  Which passes it along to `np.histogram`

```
s.hist(normed=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Great post. Not quite what I was looking for though. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

The [library Dexplot](https://dexplo.org/dexplot) is capable of returning relative frequencies of groups. Currently, you'll need to bin the `age` variable in pandas with the `cut` function. You can then, use Dexplot.

```
titanic['age2'] = pd.cut(titanic['age'], range(0, 110, 10))
```

Pass the variable you would like to count (`age2`) to the `count` function. Subdivide the counts with the `split` parameter and normalize by `age2`. Also, this might be a good time for a stacked bar plot

```
dxp.count('age2', data=titanic, split='survived', stacked=True, normalize='age2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be better if you create a function that splits your data in age groups

```
# This function splits our data frame in predifined age groups
def cutDF(df):
    return pd.cut(
        df,[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], 
        labels=['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61-70', '71-80'])


data['AgeGroup'] = data[['Age']].apply(cutDF)
```

Then you can plot your graph as follows:

```
survival_per_age_group = data.groupby('AgeGroup')['Survived'].mean()

# Creating the plot that will show survival % per age group and gender
ax = survival_per_age_group.plot(kind='bar', color='green')
ax.set_title("Survivors by Age Group", fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel("Age Groups")
ax.set_ylabel("Percentage")
ax.tick_params(axis='x', top='off')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', right='off')
plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')             

# Importing the relevant fuction to format the y axis 
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y)))
plt.show()
```